# Giving property to custom control but its not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created custom control which has label and star indicating required.I want to change the color of label.so i am giving ForeColor property to control but its not applying.

```
<asp:LabelwithRequired ID="MessageLabelwithRequired" 
runat="server" Text="Message" Required="True" Forecolor="Red"></asp:LabelwithRequired>
```

Properties which i have exposed in control only that properties are getting applied but other properties are not applying.

Can anybody help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Just check, have you retrieved your custom control from Asp.net Label control. If not try inheriting from it and than it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a server control.Then you need to add it into reference and also toolbox as a component.Then you can use it using drag and drop.Also it show the property call `TextColor` in Property Window.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

[assembly: TagPrefix("CustomeLable", "CsLable")]

namespace ServerControl2
{
    [DefaultProperty("Lable")]
    [DisplayName("Custome Lable")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:CustomeLable runat=server></{0}:CustomeLable>")]
    public class CustomeLable : CompositeControl
    {
        Panel p;
        Label lbl;

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return lbl.Text.Replace('*',' ').Trim();
            }

            set
            {
                lbl.Text = value + " *"; // you asked above
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        [DefaultValue("Black")]
        [Localizable(true)]
        public Color TextColor
        {
            get
            {
                return lbl.ForeColor;
            }

            set
            {
                lbl.ForeColor = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            Controls.Clear();
            p = new Panel();
            lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = "Custome Lable *";
            p.Controls.Add(lbl);
            base.CreateChildControls();

        }
        protected override void RecreateChildControls()
        {
            EnsureChildControls();
        }
        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            AddAttributesToRender(writer);
            lbl.RenderControl(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

**Asp.net Web Form Code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ATButtonBarControl.Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="ServerControl2" namespace="ServerControl2" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <cc1:CustomeLable ID="CustomeLable1" runat="server" />
            <br />       
        </div>  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```